# Complexity - Dijkstras algorithm

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, complexity-theory

Lets say I have implemented dijkstras using a PriorityQueue so that adding and removing from the unvisited nodes takes O(log n).

The PQ will contain at most E nodes so to empty it we get O(E). While PQ is not empty we take the best node and remove it, visit if not visited and go through all of its neighbors (potentially adding them to the PQ).

**What I do not understand:** How can going through all neighbors (at worst V) for at worst E items not have the time-complexity of O(E*V). I have seen so many explanation that we are supposed to just look at the operations and observe how many times they will execute and draw our conclusions from this. I do not see how we can disregard the fact that we are looping through V neighbors, an empty for-loop of n items is still O(n)?

For me the final complexity seems to be O(V + E*V log E) instead of O(V + V log E). I mean there are a lot of variances but the main point is I am missing something trivial :P

Comment: The time complexity of Dijkstra's algorithm isn't `O(V + V log E)`, it's `O((E+V) log V)` improved to `O(E + V log V)` with a Fibonacci heap instead of a binary heap.

Comment: Because `E` is the *total* number of edges, so if for example every node stores the *related* edges, then the *sum* of all these edges is `E`.

Answer (score 0):

First point of terminology that you seem to have confused.  `E` is not the number of items, it is the number of edges between vertices.  `V` is the number of vertices, which (depending on context) is likely to be the number of items.

Next, "this vertex is a neighbor of that vertex" means that there is an edge between them.  Each edge contributes 2 neighbor relationships.  (One in each direction.)  Therefore `2 E` is the number of neighbor relationships that can exist, total.

Your intuition that every one of `V` nodes can have up to `V-1` neighbors for a total of `V2-V` neighbor relationships is correct - but you can tell how close you are to that worst case from the number of edges.

Therefore we wind up with the following potential work:

```
for each of E edges:
    for each vertex on that edge:
        O(1) work to check whether it was processed yet
        (processing the vertex if needed accounted for separately)

for each of V vertices:
    O(log(V)) to add to the priority queue
    O(log(V)) to remove from the priority queue
    (processing its edges accounted for separately
```

The first chunk is `O(E)`.  The second chunk is `O(V log(V))`.  The total is `O(E + V log(V))`.

Hopefully this explanation clarifies why the complexity is what it is.

Comment: I'm just confused on how I should describe it. The way I implemented we store items with node, predecessor and cost from start. I just described it as nodes as that what it looks like the most, but there can be E of them because each vertex can have multiple paths from the start.

Yes to your third paragrah, so you mean if there are V^2-V edges then that will still be just E edges or I don't really get the point.
 for loop. Why for every vertex on that edge? Why not for every neighbor of one of the vertices of the edge? I thought we go through all neighbors?

Comment: @howtopythonpls Each vertex can start multiple paths, but each vertex in the end is only arrived at from one.  Just associate each edge that extends a path with the vertex that it goes to and you'll see that you never have more things to deal with than you have vertices.